# What is the right way to share a jade template to other modules

Tags: node.js, npm, pug

So I'm getting started on a project that uses node and jade templates to generate card game prototype pdfs. To make the project more useful for others, I was considering trying to package several jade templates in my module as standard card layouts that could be extended by the user for their specific needs. The problem with this approach is that I can't really think of a good way to have their jade templates extend my jade templates without some really hairy access into the node_modules files. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the collection of your templates from your node module.

Say your module is called "tpl-cards", then you can do:

```
module.exports = {
  main_lib: function() {
    /* your main lib */
  },
  templates: [
    /* list of templates */
  ]
}
```

Then your users can do:

```
var templates = require('tpl-cards').templates;
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I have a couple of questions regarding this:
1) what is actually contained in my list of templates? Strings? Precompiled templates?
2) The extends mechanism looks like it uses a relative file path - how do I extend something I've imported in this way?